# Emacs speedbar does not show all class's methods

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

As in title, I have middle size class CPP file of ~400 lines of code. There are some new methods not being shown when unfolding my class in the speedbar frame. Looks like speedbar displays the tree from several previous iterations of my code .  P.S. Update Command doesn't help.  GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.4) . Speedbar installed from the melpa package manager.

Comment: Try M-x `semantic-force-refresh`

Comment: Does it use semantic to parse project files ? I just keep it turned off cause it does not do well with template classes -- clang- auto-complete does well. Any other alternatives ? I like the ebrowser , BUT it won't work as speedbar in separate frame. –

Answer (score 4):

I'm solving my own problem: seems speedbar ain't parse well if the semantics mode is turned off.

```
;; CEDET
(global-ede-mode 1)
(require 'semantic/sb)
(semantic-mode 1)
```